# Custom Pure Pipe in Angular2 with change detection push

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement a custom pipe in Angular 2 for the translation in our website. I made an impure pipe first but noticed that it is getting transformed for every mouseover and small events in dom. 
The other option was to implement a pure pipe but this required an input (language code) to be passed in so that change is detected .

I would like to continue with pure pipe and change the change detection strategy to OnPush. However is there any way to set the change detection strategy globally rather than specifying it in each component?

The other option is to inject the translation service which has the language code globally.Is there any option to inject a service globally like PLATFORM_PIPES or PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a service **only** on the root component (`AppComponent`) then every component or pipe or service that has it as constructor parameter gets the same instance injected.

Comment: yes,but I don't want to import and include it  in the constructor of each component

Comment: That's how injection works. There is no other way. Actually, you could inject by token instead of by type but I wouldn't suggest using it. What's the issue with importing?

Comment: Since this is the translation service it will get injected to pretty much every component in our application. So I was bit skeptical.I was thinking of injecting it like the pipe globally

Comment: If you inject it to the pipe and provide the pipe globally, there shouldn't be anything else to do.

Comment: Hi Gunter, Pipe transform won't be called in Angular 2 unless the args passed into the pipe changes.The other option is to make it a stateful pipe

Comment: Right. I got a bit confused about what the actual problem is. I guess you would need to pass the language as parameter for Angular to call the pipe when the language changes. I don't know how a stateful pipe would help if it is not being called.

Comment: In an impure pipe I can subscribe to the language change of the service inside the pipe and mark the changedetetionref of it for check. That will call the pipe transform again

Comment: Does this make sense? An impure pipe is called anyway when change detection happens. You mean with `OnPush`? Sounds like a good option. What are the downsides?

Comment: Yes, with OnPush .There is no downside I can think of,but I guess I need to specify that too in each components and might get complicated with third party UI components

Comment: Yes, you need to specify in each component. Actually, I assume if you markForCheck and Angular doesn't recognize a change, it still won't call the pipe.